# Variable losing its value

Tags: php, variables

I looked through the stack questions and answers, but didn't see anything I could directly apply here.  Maybe I'm just missing something.

The code below works fine, except when I include my where statement which refers to the value of the $wp_user_id variable.

I've checked that the variable IS actually being populated with a $user_id when the script is loaded.  It appears that the value  of this variable is lost right after the call to the conManager function, but I don't understand why.  There doesn't appear to be anything within the ConnectionManager.php file (which defines the conManager function) which would touch this variable, so I'm at a loss.

I'm a PHP hack, so go easy on me, but what is causing me to lose the value of my variable, and how do I address it?  Here's the code:

```
<?php
include_once("/home/evaluate/public_html/admin/php/ConnectionManager.php");
header('Content-type:text/javascript;charset=UTF-8');

$wp_user_id = $_GET["user"];

$json1=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST["_gt_json"]));
$pageNo = $json1->{'pageInfo'}->{'pageNum'};
$pageSize = $json1->{'pageInfo'}->{'pageSize'};


if(isset($json1->{'sortInfo'}[0]->{'columnId'})){
    $sortField = $json1->{'sortInfo'}[0]->{'columnId'};
}
else{
    $sortField = "miles_on_oil";
}    

if(isset($json1->{'sortInfo'}[0]->{'sortOrder'})){
    $sortOrder = $json1->{'sortInfo'}[0]->{'sortOrder'};
}
else{
    $sortOrder = "ASC";
}    

if($json1->{'sortInfo'}[0]->{'sortOrder'} == "defaultsort"){
    $sortField = "miles_on_oil";
    $sortOrder = "ASC";
}


 if($json1->{'filterInfo'}[0]->{'value'} != "") {

for ($i = 0; $i < count($json1->{'filterInfo'}); $i++) {
    if($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "equal"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . "='" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "' ";
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "notEqual"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . "!='" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "' ";    
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "less"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . "<" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . " ";
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "lessEqual"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . "<=" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . " ";    
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "great"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . ">" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . " ";
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "greatEqual"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . ">=" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . " ";        
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "like"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . " LIKE '%" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "%' ";        
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "startWith"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . " LIKE '" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "%' ";        
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == "endWith"){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . " LIKE '%" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "' ";                
    }elseif($json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'logic'} == ""){
        $filter .= $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'columnId'} . " LIKE '%" . $json1->{'filterInfo'}[$i]->{'value'} . "' ";    
        }            
    $filter .= " AND ";

}
}

else {
    $filter = '';
    }


//print_r ($json1);
//die;



// Temp TEsting Values



// End Temp Testing Values



$conManager = new ConManager();
$conManager->getConnection();


 if($json1->{'action'} == 'load'){



//to get how many records totally.
$sql = "select count(*) as cnt from oil_analysis_data where $filter user_id = '".$wp_user_id."'";
$handle = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_object($handle);
$totalRec = $row->cnt;



$sql2 = "select * from oil_analysis_data where $filter user_id = '".$wp_user_id."' ORDER BY " . $sortField . " " . $sortOrder . " limit " . ($pageNo - 1)*$pageSize . ", " . $pageSize;
  $handle2 = mysql_query($sql2);

  $retArray2 = array();

while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($handle2)) {

//    Grab Vehicle Make, Model & Year "Names" from their respective tables & insert into the array

         $year = "select Name from vehicle_data_years where ID =  {$row2['list1']}";
         $year1 = mysql_query($year);
         $year2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($year1); 
         $year3 = $year2['Name'];

         $make = "select Name from vehicle_data_makes where ID =  {$row2['list2']}";
         $make1 = mysql_query($make);
         $make2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($make1); 
         $make3 = $make2['Name'];

         $model = "select Name from vehicle_data_all where ID =  {$row2['list3']}";
         $model1 = mysql_query($model);
         $model2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($model1); 
         $model3 = $model2['Name'];

    $row2['list1'] = $year3;
    $row2['list2'] = $make3; 
    $row2['list3'] = $model3; 

// Grab Motor oil Viscosity, Brand & Product "Names" from their respective tables & insert into the array

         $visc = "select name from viscosity where id =  {$row2['viscosity']}";
         $visc1 = mysql_query($visc);
         $visc2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($visc1); 
         $visc3 = $visc2['name'];

         $brand = "select brandname from oil_brand where brandid =  {$row2['brand']}";
         $brand1 = mysql_query($brand);
         $brand2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($brand1); 
         $brand3 = $brand2['brandname'];

         $product = "select product_name from oil_data where id =  {$row2['product']}";
         $product1 = mysql_query($product);
         $product2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($product1); 
         $product3 = $product2['product_name'];


    $row2['viscosity'] = $visc3;
    $row2['brand'] = $brand3; 
    $row2['product'] = $product3; 


    if($row2['bypass_filtration'] == 1) {

        $row2['bypass_filtration'] = "<img src='http://themotoroilevaluator.com/admin/php/crud/images/checkmark.png' style='border: 0px;'>";
        }

    else {$row2['bypass_filtration'] = "";
        }

    if($row2['oil_change'] == 1) {

        $row2['oil_change'] = "<img src='http://themotoroilevaluator.com/admin/php/crud/images/checkmark.png' style='border: 0px;'>";
        }

    else {$row2['oil_change'] = "";
        }

    $retArray[] = $row2;



    }

$analysis_data = json_encode($retArray);

$ret = "{data:" . $analysis_data .",\n";
$ret .= "pageInfo:{totalRowNum:" . $totalRec . "},\n";
$ret .= "recordType : 'object'}";
echo $ret;


}



?>
```

Comment: Lots of code there... I don't even see `$user_id`, you mean `$wp_user_id`?

Comment: Reduce your code to reasonable minimum that demonstrates an issue

Comment: I recognize this is a long portion of code.  Probably the last half is unnecessary, but I wanted it to be clear what the purpose of the file was, in case it helped clarify things.

Comment: Nevermind.  It would appear that my problem actually resulted from a change in my code that I had forgotten about.  I changed $_REQUEST['user'] to $_GET['user'], thinking that, in this case, since the value was being passed as a URL query string, that wouldn't be a problem.

To be honest, I'm still not entirely sure why that made a difference - although I can research that on my own.  But, at any rate, changing that back corrected my problem entirely.

Thanks to those who responded, though.  Even if not solutions to my actual problem, the information from both turned out to be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm curious, why do you add a semi colon after the `$wp_user_id;` ? I've noticed you doing this in more than one place. This may be the culprit.

```
$filter user_id = '".$wp_user_id;."'";
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo.  Corrected here in the post and in my file, but it still doesn't solve the issue because the value seems to be lost before I ever get to that place in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.  It would appear that my problem actually resulted from a change in my code that I had forgotten about.  I changed $_REQUEST['user'] to $_GET['user'], thinking that, in this case, since the value was being passed as a URL query string, that wouldn't be a problem.

To be honest, I'm still not entirely sure why that made a difference - although I can research that on my own.  But, at any rate, changing that back corrected my problem entirely.

Thanks to those who responded, though.  Even if not solutions to my actual problem, the information from both turned out to be very useful.

Answer (score -1):

Any hacker can severely screw up or delete your database because of the way you use direct user provided data to build up your SQL query. Please instead read up on [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), and the use of PHP prepared statements.

[Relevant](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Sky,  Thank you for pointing this out. I did read up on the SQL injection problem as you suggested and understand the issue now.  In this particular example, since the only piece of information that the user could directly submit would be the "user id" via the URL query string (not through a form field), it seems like this might be a bit more difficult.  However, just in case, if I added the following to my code would this generally protect me from such an attack?  

     $wp_user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($wp_user_id);

Comment: Michael, that is probably a good first step, but I recommend that going forward, you use a prepared statement to perform all database interaction. The PHP mysqli class is really easy to use and let's you not worry about how tainted the data you receive may be.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I'll have to take a look into this.  As I mentioned in my post, I'm really not much of a programmer.  I generally am better at taking other people's scripts and tweaking them to do what I want.  But, I'm learning, and I'm certain your suggestions will be helpful to me moving forward.